# Vitest throws error upon import statement of file

Tags: javascript, testing, three.js, vitest

I'm using Vitest to test my JavaScript project that uses the Three.js graphics library. The *generateRandomMoves* function in **cube.js** doesn't depend on anything in **index.js** to run. The test appears to fail because cube.js imports index.js, which imports the Three.js file **orbitcontrols.js**. My goal is to test functions in cube.js using Vitest. How do I do resolve the issue I am facing to do this?

Directory structure

[image]

**cube.test.js**

```
import { generateRandomMoves } from "./cube.js";

it("should return an array of random moves with a length of 'difficulty'", () => {
  // Arrange
  const difficulty = 2;

  // Act
  const randomMoves = generateRandomMoves(difficulty);

  // Assert
  expect(randomMoves.length).toBe(difficulty);
});
```

**cube.js** imports

[image]

**index.js** imports

[image]

Error message:

[image]